# head of linked list keeps changing

Tags: c, shell, while-loop, linked-list, null

I have an assignment where we are making a task controller and I am stuck on creating a linked list to hold my commands/tasks (ex: if the user types "ls" and then types "list" the output would be Task 1: ls) However after i type list, I notice that the head of the linked list keeps changing for some reason and the output i get is Task 1: list when list should not be popping up in the linked list because i have a portion in my main method where if the user types list it prints out the linked list using a while loop. Im not sure if the reason it's not working is because Im doing majority of the code in a while loop thats in a mainmethod which essentially keeps checking for user input or if Im writing my structure wrong(i cant change anything my teacher has already wriiten so the while loop. I have searched the bowels of google to see what im doing wrong and I am truly stumped on this.

```
typedef struct taskNode{
        int pid;
        int taskNumber;
        char *cmd;
        int status;
        int exit_code;
        //struct taskNode *next;

}taskNode_t;

typedef struct node{
        taskNode_t *data;
        struct node *next;
}node_t;
//holds the size of linked lisst
int size;

//creates task
taskNode_t *createTask(char *cmdline, int size){
        taskNode_t *newNode;
        newNode = (taskNode_t*)malloc(sizeof(taskNode_t));
        newNode->pid = 0;
        newNode->taskNumber=size;
        newNode->cmd = cmdline;
        newNode->status = LOG_STATE_READY;
        newNode->exit_code=0;
        return newNode;
}

node_t * createNode(){
        node_t *temp;
        temp = (node_t*)malloc(sizeof(node_t));
        temp->next = NULL;
        return temp;
}

`
node_t* insertFirst(node_t *head, taskNode_t *data){
        node_t *temp,*p;
        node_t *head2 = head;
        temp = createNode();
        temp->data = data;
        if(head2 == NULL){
                head2 = temp;
                printf("resetting head\n");

        }else{
                p = head;
                while(p->next != NULL){
                        p = p->next;

                }
                p->next = temp;

        }
        size++;
        return head2;
}


















    /* The entry of your task controller program */
    int main() {
    size = 0;
    node_t *head = NULL;

    //teachers code
    char cmdline[MAXLINE];        /* Command line */
    char *cmd = NULL;
    /* Intial Prompt and Welcome */
    log_kitc_intro();
    log_kitc_help();

    /* Shell looping here to accept user command and execute */
    while (1) {
            if(head == NULL){
                printf("headis null\n");
            }
        char *argv[MAXARGS+1];        /* Argument list */

        Instruction inst;           /* Instruction structure: check parse.h */

        /* Print prompt */
        log_kitc_prompt();

        /* Read a line */
     // note: fgets will keep the ending '\n'
        errno = 0;
        if (fgets(cmdline, MAXLINE, stdin) == NULL) {
            if (errno == EINTR) {
                continue;
            }
            exit(-1);
        }


        if (feof(stdin)) {  /* ctrl-d will exit text processor */
          exit(0);
        }


        /* Parse command line */
        if (strlen(cmdline)==1)   /* empty cmd line will be ignored */
          continue;

        cmdline[strlen(cmdline) - 1] = '\0';        /* remove trailing '\n' */

        cmd = malloc(strlen(cmdline) + 1);          /* duplicate the command line */
         snprintf(cmd, strlen(cmdline) + 1, "%s", cmdline);


            /* Bail if command is only whitespace */
            if(!is_whitespace(cmd)) {
            initialize_command(&inst, argv);    /* initialize arg lists and instruction */
            parse(cmd, &inst, argv);            /* call provided parse() */


            if (DEBUG) {  /* display parse result, redefine DEBUG to turn it off */
                debug_print_parse(cmd, &inst, argv, "main (after parse)");
            }


            /* After parsing: your code to continue from here */
            /*================================================*/
           //MY CODE

       
                if(strcmp("list", cmdline)==0){

                   node_t *current;
                   current = head;
                   while(current!= NULL){
                           printf("%s\n", current->data->cmd);
                        
                        current=current->next;
                   }else{

                  log_kitc_task_init(size+1,cmd); //prints of "adding task to so and so, works good
                  taskNode_t *newNode = createTask(cmd,size+1);//creates the task node holding the     task info
                  if(head!=NULL)
                  printf("head:%s",head->data->cmd); //me trying to see what head is
                  head = insertFirst(head,newNode); //inserts the task node into a linked list


                  }
Output:

user: ls
"Adding ls to controller"
user: cat program.c
"adding cat program.c to controller"

user:list

expected output

task 1: ls
task 2 : cat program.c

my output

task 1: [blank] 
task 2:  list
```

Comment: To start with there is no reason to parse the command line args in the loop. Second where is 'parse' and what is it for?

Comment: parse(cmd, &inst, argv); It's in the part ofthe teachers code, I can't touch anything he has already written so I have to  insert my code on the line where it says continue from here. I assume it gets the command line and checks if there's white space and saves the command line to cmd and cmdline

Comment: I think the while loop is overwriting the head node each time it runs because when i check the head node after the first loop it's gone